# Getting a single Dictionary element into a variable

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, casting

I have a variable:

```
reas : [String:[User]]?
```

I want to sort it and put it in another view controller variable

```
vc.OrederReas = reas.sorted { $0.1.count > $1.1.count }
```

I'm getting an error that orderReas needs to be of type

```
[Dictionary<String, [User]>.Element]()
```

Which I made, Now I want to put a signal element from orderReas (which should be String:[User], and maybe sometimes all the elements, but this is not the issue).

but I don't know how to define it, I'm getting errors such as:

```
Cannot assign value of type 'Dictionary<String, [User]>.Element' (aka '(key: String, value: Array<User>)') to type '[Dictionary<String, [User]>.Element]' (aka 'Array<(key: String, value: Array<User>)>')
```

But I can't define a variable as

```
var OrederReas = Dictionary<String, [User]>.Element
```

To sum up I want a variable which holds [String:[User]], sort him into another variable, and Another variable which will hold one either one element or all the elements from the original variable.

Thank you!

Comment: When you sort a dictionary the result is a collection of key value pairs (the dictionary element) `var OrederReas: [(key: String, value: [User])]`

Comment: Thanks @leo, And how can I define a single element from OrederReas?

Comment: `let element: (key: String, value: [User])`

Answer (score 0):

When you are sorting a Dictionary the result will be a array Tuple of Key and Value.
in your case, if you want to have dictionaries of the same type you can convert your Result(Tuple) to a Dictionary so you can do this:

```
let tupleOrederReas = reas.sorted {  $0.value.count > $1.value.count }
let dictionaryOrederReas = tupleOrederReas.reduce(into: [:]) { $0[$1.key] = $1.value }

//Finally Pass the Dictionary to VC variable

vc.OrederReas = dictionaryOrederReas
```

Comment: Better to use `$0.value.count > $1.value.count` to improve readability. And `$0[$1.key] = $1.value` Note that dictionary is an unordered collection by design.

Comment: @LeoDabus As you suggested I replaced the numbers with key and value for readability.